# Glue Kohler flush valve together?

Tags: repair, toilet, adhesive, plastic

I have a Kohler toilet with a canister flush valve (part 1084017-6-A).

The top of the "guide" piece in the flush valve assembly (where the hose attaches) broke off, so the toilet functions but very little water goes into the bowl when it refills (almost all goes into the tank).

I ordered a new valve assembly, but in the meantime I thought I'd try gluing the thing as a temporary fix before the part arrives.  Does anyone know what kind of plastic that kind of product might be made of?

Comment: If I understand correctly, can't you just tape that hose in place until you get the new unit?

Comment: I didn't see a way to tape it.  I ended up using superglue, which so far is working very well.